# Cannot edit a reference between two existing tables in Ruby on Rails via form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have two tables in Ruby on Rails, Movies and Directors. Movies has belongs_to association to director, and director has has_many association to movies. I can create both just fine, but when i try to edit a movie to include its director via a dropdown(using form.collection_select) and click update i get this message:

1 error prohibited this movie from being saved:

```
Director must exist
```

This is the code for the dropdown (its labeled in my native language, sorry about that)

"

```
<%= form.label :director_id, "Režisér", style: "display: block" %>
<%= form.collection_select(:director_id, Director.all, :id, :first_name, {:prompt => 'Vyberte režiséra'}, :selected => @movie.director_id ) %>
```

"

I'm a newbie to Ruby on Rails and my search on this issue has so far been unsuccessful and i have no idea how to ask Mr Google correctly

Comment: Are you whitelisting the `:director_id` property in your controller? You can also get rid of `:selected => @movie.director_id` - the `collection_select` helper will automatically do that for you.

Comment: That did it! I can't believe it was so simple, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. You should move your edit into an answer and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved thanks to max's comment below, i simply needed to add the director_id reference parameter to my movies_controller.rb like so:

def movie_params

```
  params.require(:movie).permit(:name, :release_date, :description, :director_id)
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).